Switching between two data frames using an ifelse statement in R
I have a variable finaldf, and I want it to represent either data frame a or b depending on a condition. But I end up with a list instead of a data frame in R. How do I create an ifelse statement that can switch between two data frames?
a = data.frame(a = c(1:10), b = c(1:10))
b = data.frame(c = c(11:20), d = c(11:20))

g = 'testB'

finaldf = ifelse(g == "testB", b, a)

Currently, c returns a list, but I just want a dataframe.
> finaldf  
[[1]]
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

> class(finaldf)
[1] "list"


I want finaldf to equal dataframe B, not a list with B's values.

Use if else not ifelse.

ifelse is for vectors, as the help page starts, it "returns a value with the same shape as" the input. You want the much more general finaldf = if(g == "testB") b else a here.

Definitely use if-else instead of ifelse, as shown in the dupe targets, but just for fun (and not entirely right): data.table::fifelse(rep(g, ncol(b)) == "testB", b, a)
